# Reading odd XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I did a search through this site and through google and didn't really find anything similar to this..as most of the examples I ran into are of a more normal, cleaner standard?  I just need to figure out how to read the Name=, Handle=, and Tweet=.  thanks for any help

all i have so far is this:

```
doc = XDocument.Load("twitterTrio.xml");    
var temp = doc.Descendants("tweets")....
```

xml i'm trying to read:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dtvTwitter>
  <tweets>
    <RcsTweet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="NFL on ESPN" Handle="@ESPNNFL" Tweet="So @RGIII can pass, run and now he can BEAT BOX??  (MUST SEE VIDEO) --&gt; http://t.co/sexsrtskfZ" ImageUrl="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3573179175/26a4fd77256691aedab2ecbc60c7b86c_normal.jpeg" />
    <RcsTweet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="NFL Retweet" Handle="@NFLRT" Tweet="RT @NOTSportsCenter: BREAKING: There's a reason #Jets coach Rex Ryan keeps naming Mark Sanchez starter: he's blind. http://t.co/zEPKqfAV1o" ImageUrl="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000203929393/ef2529f3f226d69c0731c7469f1c51ba_normal.jpeg" />
    <RcsTweet xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="ProFootballTalk" Handle="@ProFootballTalk" Tweet="Bernard Pollard says Justin Hunter can destroy a defense, be a star and help the Titans win a championship http://t.co/GPJcJXXqvg" ImageUrl="http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2390753568/qzhbfg9lgfrkmkrt4l4u_normal.jpeg" />
  </tweets>
</dtvTwitter>
```

Comment: i did google... everything is of the format <tweets><name><handle>.. what i pasted is not

Comment: Found with googling "xml lingo": http://tools.arlut.utexas.edu/gash2/doc/xml/introtoxml.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("RcsTweet");
    for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
    {
        string name = elemList[i].Attributes["Name"].Value;
        string handle = elemList[i].Attributes["Handle"].Value;
        string tweet = elemList[i].Attributes["Tweet"].Value;
    }
```

Comment: ah so it's called attributes... if i knew that i coulda googled and figured it out =T  gonna try it brb

Comment: thank you, this worked.  i'm not familiar with xml.. if i knew that the handle's inside where called attributes i would've been able to find it so easy =T  tyvm

Comment: And when you come across one where there is no `Tweet` attribute this code will throw... IMO you are almost always better off just using XML serialization or at least something that that is more tolerant of xml that isn't exactly what you expect.

Comment: this is pretty much an xml file that my program has to read.. so i'm not the one writing the xml file unfortunatley =T

Answer (score 2):

I generally prefer to use XML serialization and let .Net deal with the unexpected cases

```
public class dtvTwitter
{
    public tweets tweets{get;set;}
}
public class tweets
{
    [XmlElement("RcsTweet")]
    public List<RcsTweet> RcsTweets { get; set; }

}
public class RcsTweet
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Tweet { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Handle { get; set; }
}
```

then just:

```
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(dtvTwitter));
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("myfile.xml");
        dtvTwitter val = (dtvTwitter)ser.Deserialize(sr);
```

to get the deserialized graph